# Puma rails server not starting in Daemon mode on EC-2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2

I want to run Rails application on EC2 machine. When my SSH session terminates the rails server shutdown. I want to run the rails server in the background. I used `rails s -d` command to run rails daemon mode.
But it seems like Puma is not started. This is the message I receive and after that process terminates.

```
Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.6 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
```

Usually when I run rails server I get

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.6 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.11.0 (ruby 2.3.5-p376), codename: Love Song
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

What is going wrong? Is puma server booting up but not starting?

Comment: It's normal when you run `puma` in daemon mode, just 1-2 lines of log present to you. You can check if it is running or not by using `ps -ef | grep puma` or `ps -ef | grep rails`

Comment: Did you just guess that the server didn't start? Or did you try to connect to the server and load some pages? How did you do that? What happened?

Comment: It is not running. I want to run rails in Daemon .What should i do?

Comment: @spickermann able to run with rails server command but had no luck with rails s -d command.